# Can't save any polygon layer: getting strange error message

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, encoding, save

After using QGIS 3.12 for some time, I ran across a problem where I could not save any polygon that had a text field. Even if I create a new project with nothing in it, make a polygon, and add a text field, I get the following error when I try and save the layer.

[image: error]

I tried deleting the QGIS 3.12 directory (I downloaded it with the web installer) and installing QGIS 3.10 through the standalone installer, but the same issue comes up even on a fresh install! Is there some kind of temporary directory used by the program that I need to clear as well?

Comment: What file encoding do you select creating the shape file? Do you use Chines character set? Is it the same for GeoPackage layer?

Comment: You can't create shapefiles with non-asci attribute names

Comment: I used the UTF-16 encoding to create the layer, I assume the encoding of the file it creates is the same. I did not use any Chinese character set. As you can see in the error message, the name of the field was "test", in ASCII characters.